# How to add a forgotten SSD card to Windows 10 drives?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I installed Windows 10 on my Asus-n552vw which has 2 TB hard disk + 128 GB SSD card. When I was partitioning my PC, I deleted all previous partitions and re partitioned the 2 TB disk, but I forgot to create a new partition on SSD card and installed windows. Now, how can I add the SSD card as a new drive to my windows?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your disk management and it should be listed. A shortcut would be to hit <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (which should open the run dialog) and type `diskmgmt.msc` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

As duDe mentioned it might be a nice option to install your OS on the SSD though since it will likely be a bit faster to boot.

Comment: In windows 8 and up, you can right-click the start menu and access Disk Management from the menu. WIN+X also gives that menu.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install windows 10 on SSD (and this make sense) you need a clean installation like [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install-winpc/clean-install-of-windows-10-os-on-new-ssd-best/9186ae98-b2b4-4b7a-b3ff-0b053ce2d1c9) (by [DaveM121](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/profile/3fbea464-6573-4f0b-a07d-2f860fb1f8d1)):

Once you have the bootable installation media created:

> - Shut down your system. remove the old HDD and install the SSD (there should be only the SSD attached to your system during the installation
>     process)
> - Insert the Bootable Installation Media
> - Go into your BIOS and if SATA Mode is not set to AHCI, change it
> - Change the boot order so the Installation Media is top of the boot order
> - Save changes to BIOS and Reboot your system
> - The Installation should start
> - During the installation process skip the steps which ask for a product key and select the option 'I am Reinstalling Windows 10 on
>     this PC', and activation will not be an issue, your PC will have a
>     digital entitlement stored on the Microsoft Servers
> - During the installation process, your system will reboot, at that point, you may need to go into your BIOS and change the boot order so
>     your system boots from your Hard Drive, otherwise the installation may
>     start all over again - do not remove the installation media at this
>     point
> - When Window 10 has finished installing and the desktop appears, shut your system down
> - If you have a second HDD bay install the old HDD into it and start your system
> - Make sure you can see both drives in Windows File Explorer, if not you may need to restart a couple of times for Windows to recognise
>     both drives
> - Install any required drivers (can be obtained from the support page on the Website of the manufacturer of your system

Comment: I have installed windows on the HDD hard, and don't want install it on SSD. I only forgot to create a partition on SSD when I installed the windows and now I am seeking a way to add it as a hard drive (Like D, E, ETC.) to my installed Windows.

Comment: Why not? In this case (OS on SSD) your system would be running faster ...

Comment: Cause I need a C drive with 1 TB space. SSD card's storage is not enough.